# All elements in array before selected being deleted

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, processing, p5.js

Probably just something dumb but I'm rewriting Galaga in p5.js for a university assignment and towards the beginning I'm at destroying enemies. When a bullet is fired and it hits say the third enemy on the screen, all of the enemies before it are being destroyed.

The enemies array is just a simple array where enemy objects are pushed: `enemies = [];`

The destroy function for the enemies is

```
this.die = function() {
    enemies.splice(enemies[this.index], 1);
}
```

And the loop is

```
for( var b = 0; b < player.bullets.length; b++) {
    for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        var bullet = player.bullets[b];
        if(collision(bullet.x, enemies[i].x, bullet.y, enemies[i].y, 20, 55, 40, 55)) {
            enemies[i].die();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great

Comment: What's exactly the question here ?

Comment: not remove (.splice()) the destroyed element, but replace it by another value that not shown into screen

Comment: What does `enemies[this.index]` return? If it's not a number then it's not going to react properly. Also don't forget that looping beginning to end, once you splice, you are changing the size of the array, incrementing `i` causing a skip. eg, if `i` was 3 and you delete index 3, what was at index 4 is now 3 but you increment `i` to 4 without checking the new 3. Either go from end to beginning or decrement `i` when you splice to supplement the upcoming increment.

Comment: Does it work if you do `enemies.splice(i, 1);` instead of `enemies[i].die();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters to `splice` are the start index (the first elment) which has top be deleted and the number of elements.

So the statement

> ```js
> enemies.splice(enemies[this.index], 1);
> ```

doesn't seem to be correct at all. Possibly the statement

```js
enemies.splice(this.index, 1);
```

would do what you want, if `this.index` would be the index of the enemy in the array. But that won't be the case, if you've delete a previously arranged enemy from the array.

I recommend to do `enemies.splice(i, 1);` instead of `enemies[i].die();`:

```js
for( var b = 0; b < player.bullets.length; b++) {
    for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        var bullet = player.bullets[b];
        if(collision(bullet.x, enemies[i].x, bullet.y, enemies[i].y, 20, 55, 40, 55)) {
            enemies.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note, once an element was removed from the list, the the attribute `.index` of the following elements hast to be updated.